# Script, save all $input into 1 variable

Tags: bash, variables

**Example:**

```
bash script.sh "hello world"
```

(in script `echo "$1"`)

```
hello world
```

**Question:**

```
bash script.sh "good" "morning" "everybody"
```

What do I have to write in my script to output directly:

```
goodmorningeverybody
```

So, in general, I want `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ... (can be 100 but I don't know) to be saved in one variable for example `VAR1`.

Comment: Do you really want all the spaces gone? What are you planning to do with the variable once you have it?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, The script does something like this script.sh '12' '+' "23" "*" "33" and I want to calculate it, so the output must be "12+23*33" and then command bc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to all the positional arguments with `$*` and `$@`.

From [3.4.2 Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

> *
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>
> @
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …. If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

So to get `good morning everybody` as output you could just use `echo "$*"` or `echo "$@"`.

In general `@` is the more useful of the two variables.

However, if you really want the worlds all smushed together the way you indicate then you have a few options.

The most straightforward of which is a simple loop:

```
for word; do
    s+=$word
done
```

(`for` without the `in <list>` part operates on the positional arguments).

However, you can also do this with `*` by controlling `IFS`.

So you could also do `s=$(IFS=; echo "$*")`. You want/need the sub-shell to avoid setting `IFS` for the current shell.

Comment: Using IFS like this is a good idea, but a subshell is a very expensive way to do simple string manipulation.  An alternative is to localize IFS in a function.  For example (all on one line because it's in a Stackoverflow comment): `function concat { local IFS=; concat_return="$*"; } ; concat good morning everybody ; echo "$concat_return"`.

Comment: @pjh While true that's only "better" if you don't mind the global variable/side-effect aspect of that function usage but yes.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I agree that using a variable to return the concatenated string is not necessarily "better" than the alternative that uses a subshell.  The dangers associated with the variable can be hugely reduced by localizing it in the caller, before calling `concat`.  There is no perfect solution because Bash has no (generally) good way to return non-trivial values from functions.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

```
#!/bin/sh

var=$(printf '%s' "$@")
echo "$var"
```

or even better, credits to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) :

```
printf -v var '%s' "$@"
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg; do
    str+="$arg"
done

echo "$str"
```

Output :

```
goodmorningeverybody
```

Note :

`"$@"` expands to each positional parameter as its own argument: "$1" "$2" "$3"...

Comment: In `bash`, you can save a fork using `printf -v var '%s' "$@"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a loop:

```
for x in "$@"; do
  input="$input$x"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Shell-Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="$*"
VAR=${VAR// /}
echo $VAR
```

---

#### Example

```
$ script.sh "good" "morning" "everybody"
goodmorningeverybody
```